# Can I perform an XMLHttpRequest if I don't know the response type?

Tags: javascript, binary, xmlhttprequest

I wish to perform an `XMLHttpRequest` to `GET` a resource, but the catch is that the resource can be in two different formats, and I don't know which one. The first one is a textual `application/json`, in which case I want a `string` or an already parsed object; and the second one is a binary `application/zip`, in which case I want a `Blob` that I can then process with JSZip. I could always request it as a `Blob`, check the response headers, and then use a `FileReader` to convert it to a `string` if necessary, but this feels kinda clunky. Is there a better way? Browser compatibility requirement: IE10+ and the latest whatever else.

Comment: You can always check if the first and last character of the response string are `[` and `]` or `{` and `}`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir - It would be enough with the first character even. However if it's binary data, the string will almost certainly contain unusable garbage since it will be mutilated by the UTF-8 parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to set `.responseType` to `Blob`, check `.type` of `.response`. If `.type` is `"application/json"`, use `FileReader.prototype.readAsText()` to get `JSON`, else use `Blob` `.response`.

You can also perform a `HEAD` request before the actual request, check `Content-Type` header to determine how to process response of actual request.

Comment: Sending for `HEAD` is one idea, but it doesn't seem any more elegant than the `FileReader` approach. That too feels kinda unnecessary, since XMLHttpRequest already has the capacity to parse UTF-8 strings by itself. But I guess that's the best way.